# Молуль POSIX::1003

Tags: linux, perl, unix, posix

В [этом](https://metacpan.org/release/POSIX-1003) модуле (как я понял из источника) более 1200 функций. О каких вообще функциях идёт речь? Описаны ли эти функции в самом стандарте POSIX:1003, и где можно детально ознакомиться с этими функциями, и прочитать более подробно?

Comment: [IEEE Std 1003.1™-2017 (Revision of IEEE Std 1003.1-2008)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), конкретно [system interfaces](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/functions.html)

Comment: Оформите как ответ, плиз!